# React js Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'allowed'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Getting this warning but code is working fine
Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'allowed'
If i create a hook state for allowed then there is no warning but the code doesn't work. How can i declare a variable without using a useState. Code is attached.

```
const checkAllowed = async () => {
    let allowed = 1;
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/courses/eachstage/" + props.data.CourseID)
      .then(async (res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          await axios
            .get("http://localhost:4000/api/courses/allow/" + res.data[i].StID)
            .then(async (response) => {
              if (response.data === 0) {
                allowed = 0;
              }
            });
        }
      });
    return allowed;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning is occurring because you are declaring `allowed` outside of a `for` loop, then modifying it within a function defined within the `for` loop). This is discouraged because it *may* not behave as you expect.

1. You can declare the async response handler outside of the loop, and pass it in as a parameter instead of declaring it inline.
2. You can use `reduce` over the results instead of a for loop.

You may also want to not await within the loop, and instead return an array of promises that you await a `Promise.all`. That would let you do more of the requests in parallel

More details can be seen here: 
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to return but try this, a little more tidy and the scope works better

```
const checkAllowed = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/eachstage/${props.data.CourseID}`)
    const arrAllow = await Promise.all(data.map(async ({ StID }) => {
      return await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/courses/allow/${StID}`)
    }))

    const allowFind = arrAllow.find((data) => data === 0)

    return !Boolean(allowFind) ? 1 : 0
  }
```

Comment: id didn't work. actually i am have a table of course, stages and questions in my database. There are three categories of questions in my db. first i need to get all stages of a course by passing the courseID which is done in first axios call. Then i need to check that there should be atleast 20 questions in every category of a stage.That is done by 2nd axios call in which i pass the stage id and it checks that it has 20 questions in every category or not and return 1 or 0. If any of the stages return 0 then i need to update allow to 0 and return it. Otherwise allow should be 1.

Comment: I adjusted it a little bit and that worked. Thanks brother.